# Apache Reverse Proxying CGI scripts

Tags: apache, cgi, reverse-proxy

I have a web application called [routers2.cgi](http://www.steveshipway.org/software/rrd/f_routers.html) which I am trying to proxy via an Apache 2.4 proxy server which does not work at the moment.

**Direct URL to the web application server**

```
http://lab.server.com/cgi-bin/routers2.cgi
```

**Reverse proxy URL**

```
https://prod.server.com/routers2
```

**Configuration vhosts.conf from prod.server.com**

```
# routes2.cgi
ProxyPass "/routers2" "http://lab.server.com/cgi-bin/routers2.cgi"
ProxyPassReverse "/routers2" "http://lab.server.com/cgi-bin/routers2.cgi"

ProxyPass "/rrdicons" "http://lab.server.com/routers2/rrdicons"
ProxyPassReverse "/rrdicons" "http://lab.server.com/routers2/rrdicons"

ProxyPass "/graphs" "http://lab.server.com/routers2/graphs"
ProxyPassReverse "/graphs" "http://lab.server.com/routers2/graphs"
```

**Reverse proxy log samples**

```
192.168.1.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:06:40:37 +0000] "GET /routers2 HTTP/1.1" 200 3481
192.168.1.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:06:40:37 +0000] "GET /rrdicons/routers2.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
192.168.1.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:06:45:57 +0000] "GET /routers2 HTTP/1.1" 200 3481
192.168.1.10 - - [13/Jun/2017:06:45:57 +0000] "GET /rrdicons/routers2.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

**Sample URL from web application access log when accessing directly (no reverse proxy)**

```
192.168.1.9 - - [13/Jun/2017:05:50:46 +0000] "GET /routers2/graphs/devicessystem1.cfg-10.10.1.1_13-ws-x3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 27025 "http://lab.server.com/cgi-bin/routers2.cgi?rtr=devices%2Fsystem1.cfg&bars=Cami&xgtype=w&page=graph&xgstyle=x3&xmtype=routers" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
192.168.1.9 - - [13/Jun/2017:05:50:46 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/routers2.cgi?rtr=devices%2Fsystem1.cfg&bars=Cami&xgtype=w&page=menub&xgstyle=x3&if=_summary_&xmtype=options HTTP/1.1" 200 12437 "http://lab.server.com/cgi-bin/routers2.cgi" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
192.168.1.9 - - [13/Jun/2017:05:50:46 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/routers2.cgi?rtr=devices%2Fsystem1.cfg&bars=Cami&xgtype=w&page=menu&xgstyle=x3&xmtype=routers HTTP/1.1" 200 7847 "http://lab.server.com/cgi-bin/routers2.cgi" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
```

**Web application log via reverse proxy**

```
prod.server.com - - [13/Jun/2017:07:21:58 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/routers2.cgi/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3481 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
prod.server.com - - [13/Jun/2017:07:21:58 +0000] "GET /routers2/rrdicons/routers2.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://prod.server.com/routers2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
```

Does my vhosts ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse configuration look correct?
Do I need something extra since we are proxying a cgi script?

Comment: Should we assume it  doesn't work?

Comment: edited. yep, doesnt work at the moment.

Comment: Do you get anything in the web application log when accessed from the Proxy URL?

Comment: Yes, getting 200 and 304 but page contents does not fully display.